# Does the Visual Studio debugger implicitly cast smaller types to int?

Tags: visual-studio, casting, debugging

Does the Visual Studio 2008 debugger implicitly cast all smaller data types to int? I have a function with the following signature:

```
public int DoSomething(sbyte value) { ... }
```

When pass in -127 and I look at the `value` argument the Visual Studio debugger (e.g. Watch window) shows me that it has the value `0xFFFFFF81`. This is correct except for the fact that sbyte is only 8 bits wide; I would expect the debugger to show me that it is `0x81`.

Comment: Apparently, the CLR doesn't operate on integer types that are "smaller" than int; all smaller types are first widened to int when put onto the evaluation stack and then narrowed before being stored somewhere. I'm not sure if the VS debugger's described behaviour has something to do with this, but being a very similar phenomenon, I thought it worth mentioning.